# Make calls to server without specifying full URL everytime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, typescript, npm

I'm running a springbok application with a React-Typescript frontend. Everything is working fine. I currently make requests using the following method: 
`get('http://localhost:8080/api/items/allItems', {json: true})` using the **request-promise** library. I want to be able to make calls without specifying the full "localhost:8080" every time ... is there a way I can do this?

So I want to `get('api/items/allItems', {json: true})` or even `get('api/items/allItems')` without specifying json every time as well.

Are the libraries that provide this? Or even better any suggestions on how I should set this up? I tried using a **proxy** in my **package.json** but it doesn't work for these calls for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in the same port you dont need to specify the full url (its a bad practice if you do btw) if you are using CreateReactApp then u should put the proxy to the server you are trying to call and try to add `slash` `/` in the begining of the calls cause u want to call from the root so replace `get('api/items/allItems')` with `get('/api/items/allItems')`

Comment: This did not work. I received the error `n {name: "RequestError", message: "Error: Invalid URI "/api/items/allItems"", cause: Error: Invalid URI "/api/items/allItems"
    at U.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/static/js/main…, error: Error: Invalid URI "/api/items/allItems"
    at U.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/static/js/main…, options: {…}, …}`

Comment: Then the server does not recognize your url - are u sure u define ur routes correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You should proxy to the server you are trying to call, this is done by adding

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

to your package.json. Then you are able to for instance `fetch('/api/items/allItems')`, and this will get proxied to your backend resource.

Comment: I had that line and I'm able to do those calls with fetch. I'm NOT able to do them using the request-promise module that I'm using

Comment: I see. I am not familiar with that package, could you elaborate on the value it brings to your project? Maybe it's exchangeable with some other vanilla resource.